# asp.net mvc actionresult retains parameter values even after page refresh?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am setting an error Message in the viewbag to show to the user after each postback how ever I do not want to show this error message on page reload or refresh. I have tried to set it to null but it still is shown because the json parameter still contains the values of the first submit.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [CustomAuthorize(Definitions.RoleAnalystManager, Definitions.RoleProjectManager)]
        public ActionResult ExportReportAllMediaDetailsCsv(string json)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = null;

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var reportParams = serializer.Deserialize<ReportAllMediaDetailsParams>(json);


            var rows = uow.Items.Report_AllMediaDetails(reportParams.profileID, reportParams.organisationID, reportParams.startDate, reportParams.endDate).ToList();

            if (rows.Count <= 1)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "There were no results for the provided parameters, please adjust the parameters and try again.";
                return View("AllMediaDetails");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because refreshing the page actually resubmits the previous request, so your POST request is resubmitted by the browser. Can't test this at the minute; however, perhaps try setting a `bool` - `TempData["FirstLoad"]` - to true on the GET request and then do something like this in the POST method:

```
if (TempData["FirstLoad"] != null && TempData["FirstLoad"] == true)
{
    if (rows.Count <= 1)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "...";
    }
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Error = null;
    return View();
}
TempData["FirstLoad"] = false;
return View("AllMediaDetails");
```

I'm basing this on the fact that TempData is stored in the session, so its values should be retained on a refresh (rather than resubmitted as they were originally as if the value was passed as, for example, a hidden field).